# How to enable IIS to serve extension through web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, mime

I'm having some trouble with a website on a webhotel. It will not serve *.mp4 files - I simply get error 404.

Had I access to the server I'd add the mimetype in IIS, however I haven't :-(

The webhotel said they wouldn't customize their IIS for one customer, so I should enable it in my web.config instead.

Now my question is: how do I do this ?

I'm aware of the FileExtensions tag, but its default behaviour is to allow all extensions, so I doubt that's what they meant.

They're a bit slow to elaborate on these kinds of things, therefore I ask here :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Obviously, don't repeat any sections that are already in your web.config just add the children in the appropriate places.

Comment: +1 I'll try it this afternoon, but it seems like it'll do the trick. I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as I've tested it.